# Are the two 勾魂鬼 actually 黑白无常？

Tags: history

哎吆，我担心了！

“（孙悟空）掏出金箍棒，把两个勾魂鬼打成了肉酱。”

是不是这两个‘勾魂鬼’就是那两位‘黑白无常’？

他们成了肉酱的话，谁来捉拿去世人的魂呢？

There will be an imbalance between heaven and earth. Souls will pile up! Soul pollution!

Answer (score 2):

It could be, but 黑白无常 can not be eliminated obviously, they will reform.

Or, the two 勾魂鬼 just work for 黑白无常, since many people die at same times, 黑白无常 need employees.

Comment: In 百度图片, 白无常 is often an attractive woman!

Answer (score 0):

Correct : 勾魂鬼, 黑白无常, 牛头马脸 can be used interchangeably.

Wrong: They are "hell authority civil servant", so there are a bunch of them.